# How do i correctly format URL with variables in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to format the URL, let's say that I have an URL which looks like this:

```
https://example.com/api.php?getUser=12
```

But I am trying to archive something like this:

```
https://example.com/api/user/12
```

I've tried something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule api/user/ api.php?getUser=
```

But I am pretty sure i am doing something wrong and i am wondering if it's even possible (I'm not familiar with htaccess) at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RewriteRule` is incomplete and does not match the input URL. You'll need to add the user ID as a regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^api/user/([0-9]+)/?$    api.php?getUser=$1    [L]
```

The regular expression is the `([0-9]+)` part. It matches any number containing at least one digit. When rewriting the URL, Apache will take that number and place it at the `$1` placeholder.

Note that `[L]` is a RewriteRule flag. It means that if this rule matches, no further rules are processed.